# Regular expression to separate words using capital letter

Tags: regex

I have the following text

> Location:HyderabadProduct Development, Design His Own Designs And Developed The Websites. Framework: Magento: Drupal, Joomla, Ruby On Rails , Codeigniter (Any One Or A Combination). Good In Sql Database. Looking.

I need to capture just the location name - Hyderabad.

I have used `(?<=Location:).*` to remove the location tag tried with lot of other options to separate from Hyderabad but could not get an apt one.

Kindly suggest a regular expression to retrieve the location name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below regex to capture only the string `Hyderabad` which is follwed by the string `Product`,

```
(?<=Location:)(.*?)(?=Product)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/12)

OR

```
(?<=Location:)(.*?)(?=[A-Z])
```

This would capture all the characters after the string `Location` upto the next Uppercase letter.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/13)

Have added this picture just for ref - [image: While giving the regular exp]

Data captured after the regular expression [image: Captured Data]

Comment: Is there any need of capturing group?

Comment: Location: is a static text later text changes from any location name followed by any words..
;)so we need to capture the text before the second capitalized text

Comment: you could try this `(?<=Location:)(.*?)(?=[A-Z])`

Comment: thanks for the immediate response tried with the same but unable to capture any data

(?<=Location:)(.*?)(?=[A-Z])  , 
(?<=Location:)(.*?)(?=[A-Z]{1,2})

Comment: Hi avinash i tried with the following expression and it worked perfectly

(?<=Location:)(?=(^[A-Z][a-z]*))